How to put a text inside a box within a boxed environment?
I have the following LaTeX code, which makes use of a boxed environment. I want to put some of the text within a dashed and normal box, but it throws an error. Any ideas how to achieve this?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cryptocode}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcbox{\dbox}[1][]{
    on line,
    enhanced,
    frame hidden,
    interior hidden,
    sharp corners,
    size=small,
    borderline={0.4pt}{0pt}{dashed},
    #1
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{pchstack}[boxed] % whole thing needs to be wrapped with boxed as it will include a lot of subprocedures
        \begin{pcvstack}
            \begin{subprocedure}
                \procedure[linenumbering]{$\dbox{\mathsf{Init}}$}{ % this text needs to be wrapped with a dashed box
                }
            \end{subprocedure}
            \pcvspace[5pt]
            \begin{subprocedure}
                \procedure[linenumbering]{$\parbox{\mathsf{Finalize}}$}{ % this text needs to be wrapped with a solid box
                }
            \end{subprocedure}
        \end{pcvstack}
      \end{pchstack}
      \caption{...}
\end{figure}
\end{document}


If you get an error, you should copy the error message from the log as code into your question.

Your problems are independent from using boxes in boxes. There are several issues with your code, e.g., your usage of math mode. Boxex like \parbox switch to text mode. So you would need to use $…$ inside the box instead of putting the box inside $…$. Also \parbox has two mandatory arguments: the width and the content.
So would get similar errors with:
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\fbox{\mathsf{Init}}$

$\parbox{\mathsf{Finalize}}$
\end{document}

The correction would be to move the $ and to add the missing width argument to \parbox:
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\fbox{$\mathsf{Init}$}

\parbox{4cm}{$\mathsf{Finalize}$}
\end{document}

But I don't see a reason to use math mode here, so I would use, e.g.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cryptocode}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcbox{\dbox}[1][]{
    on line,
    enhanced,
    frame hidden,
    interior hidden,
    sharp corners,
    size=small,
    borderline={0.4pt}{0pt}{dashed},
    #1
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{pchstack}[boxed] % whole thing needs to be wrapped with boxed as it will include a lot of subprocedures
        \begin{pcvstack}
            \begin{subprocedure}
                \procedure[linenumbering]{\dbox{\textsf{Init}}}{ % this text needs to be wrapped with a dashed box
                }
            \end{subprocedure}
            \pcvspace[5pt]
            \begin{subprocedure}
                \procedure[linenumbering]{\parbox{4cm}{\textsf{Finalize}}}{ % this text needs to be wrapped with a solid box
                }
            \end{subprocedure}
        \end{pcvstack}
      \end{pchstack}
      \caption{...}
\end{figure}
\end{document}

Note, that \parbox also does not add a frame. So if you want a framed box you would have to use, e.g., \fbox or another box using tcolorbox.
